# Wireshark capture filters

Tags: filter, wireshark, capture

I'm new using wireshark and i'm having trouble with capture filter.
With wireshark 2.2.5, I can on the main bar "apply a display filter" and write ip.addr ==  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx( being x= number) to get a filter to a certain ip.

That's good, but when I go to Capture - capture filters, I setup name: ip filter 1 and filter: host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx but then I can't activate it?

So the question is, how do capture filters work? how can i setup multiple ip filters at the same time?

Comment: Make a nic card choice first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Wireshark User Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkDefineFilterSection.html) indicates, *"You can define filters with Wireshark and give them labels for later use."*

So while you can ***define*** a capture filter via `Capture -> Capture Filters...`, that's not where they are ***applied***.  In order to make use of any saved capture filters, you will need to apply it when you select an interface (or interfaces) to capture from.  This is done via `Capture -> Options`.  There you will see a field for entering a capture filter, and if you click on the little *"bookmark"* icon just to the left of the capture filter input field, you will see a drop-down list of saved capture filters you can choose from.  Of course you can also just type a new capture filter too; you don't necessarily have to save a capture filter ahead of time.